# Passing extra values to intents via deeplinks in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

in order for `myapp://wallet` to point to `WalletActivity` I wrote the below code, and it worked:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.WalletActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_wallet"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/MaterialThemeNoActionBar"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/title_activity_link_wallet" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="myapp"
                android:host="wallet" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I do a similar thing for `UserProfileActivity` but it crashes (obviously) inside the function `onCreate` in the line: `String id = intent.getExtras().getString("id");` because I am not sending any value for `id` to that activity's intent.

So, is there a way for me to pass the id to the intent of the called activity in this case, which I would have done in normal cases using `intent.putExtra("id", id);` in the calling activity (where `intent` is of the called activity)

Answer (score 6):

`String id = intent.getExtras().getString("id")` for the deeplink is wrong.

You can retrieve the [Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) associated with the `Intent` using

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
```

you can then using one of the getter available to retrieve your `id`, if you provide one. E.g. `myapp://wallet/test?id=100`

```
String id = data.getQueryParameter("id");
```

should give you `100`

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain a bit more using an example as well? That would help a lot! :)

Comment: I did add some details. Have a look

Comment: In addition to Blackbelt's response I just wanted to add: a very simple solution for deep linking that simplifies parsing and solves the problem of "what if the other person doesn't have the app" is branch.io -- their android SDK is open source on Github & free to use.